# Are non-abstract but state-less classes as safe for multiple inheritance as pure abstract ones?

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract

In most books and articles the only 'safe' (or at least the only advised) way of doing multiple inheritance is virtual inheritance with pure abstract base classes (which you could call virtual interfaces).

The reason is mostly stated as to avoid the Diamond Problem where one could create ambiguities for value of data members or for the implementation status of non-pure virtual functions.

Pure abstract base class don't suffer from both (no data members, no non-pure virtuals) and virtual inheritance even resolves the ambiguity of the actual memory address of the base class.

But given this explanation: If ambiguity only arises from forms of 'state' (e.g. data members, static function variables), then isn't a state-less non-abstract (maybe even with all 'final' methods) class equally safe to be the base class in a multiple inheritance hierarchy?

What possible problem am I missing?

PS: In case the answer is "If there is no virtual method, then you could use composition anyway": Besides the academic interest, I have a case where I need the property of member functions to be able to shadow free, global C-style functions, so I can't access them via a pointer-to-composition-object.

Comment: Your base classes have no `virtual` functions at all or only lack **pure** `virtual ` functions?

Comment: To circumvent the implementation ambiguity, all have to be non-virtual (and not shadowed in a sub-class) or even final. If it's overwritten in a sub-class and both sub-class and base-class are used in an inheritance tree, the compiler wouldn't know which implementation to pick

Comment: Sigh. There are valid reason for using the same stateful base class in multiple places in a hierarchy. This chatter about "the Diamond Problem" is an oversimplification that embodies a particular design style that, despite the claims made about it, is not automatically good. For example: `struct foo : list_node { /* ... */ }; struct bar : list_node { /* ... */ }; struct foo_bar : foo, bar {};` Now I can put `foo` objects into a `foo_list` with `flist.add(foo&)`, and I can put `bar` objects into a `bar_list` with `blist.add(bar&)`, and I can put `foo_bar` objects into **both** lists.

Comment: @Chaos_99: It’s not that simple, fortunately.  Virtual inheritance allows *either* (but not both) of the sides of a diamond to override a method from the shared base without the most-derived type having to nominate the override.

Comment: Why would you *rely* on shadowing free functions?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual inheritance **already** achieves the desired safety by avoiding duplicate copies of non-static members.  Variables and functions are the same in this regard: even if a base class is stateless, its non-static member **functions** are ambiguous if it is a base class more than once.

Virtual inheritance **also** handles overriding intelligently:

```
struct B {
  virtual ~B()=default;
  virtual void f()/*=0*/;
};
struct X : virtual B {};
struct Y : virtual B {
  void f() override;
};
struct D : X,Y {};

B& b();
void g() {
  b().f();    // calls Y::f
}
```

It doesn’t matter whether `B::f` is pure-virtual or not.

So being stateless is not the important part.  Moreover, if the base is stateless, having `final` members would prevent the most obvious use case of default stub implementations.  (The only other possibility would be to depend on the *value* of `this`; otherwise the functions could be static.)  So I wouldn’t necessarily encourage making a class stateless **because** it is intended for virtual inheritance (rather than simply because minimizing state is a generally good idea).

So you’re correct that non-pure-virtual functions can be *safe*, but that’s true even if the base is **stateful**.  There are still limits to the safety of multiple inheritance, of course, like ambiguity if an overload set accepts multiple direct bases.